# jQuery Validation Plugin - Submit only after checking a variable

Tags: jquery, validation, variables, submit

I have done some small validation myself and end up with either - myvalid = true or mayvalid = false. How can add this check to the validation I am doing already on my form using the Validation Plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.addMethod()` to add custom validation methods to the Validation plugin.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage

---

**Update:**

**Here's an example you can test:** http://jsfiddle.net/W8EsU/

HTML

```
<form id='theForm'>
    <input id='test_field' name='test_field' value='jQuery' />
    <br>
    <input id='test_field2' name='test_field2' value='prototypejs' />
</form>​
```

jQuery

```
   // Add a validation method to the validator plugin
   //    that can be applied as a rule to whatever fields
   //    you want. That way you get your custom validation
   //    integrated into the functionality of the plugin
$.validator.addMethod(
    "mustIncludejQuery", 
    function(value, element) { 
        return value.toLowerCase().indexOf('jquery') > -1;
    }, 
    "You must type jQuery to be valid."
);

    // Apply the custom validation to the fields
$('#theForm').validate({
   rules: {
       test_field:'mustIncludejQuery',
       test_field2:'mustIncludejQuery'
   }
});

    // Demonstrates that they will be executed
    //    like any other validation rule.
$('#theForm').valid();
​
```

Comment: +1 - This is really the way to go, add it as a rule on whichever elements you're checking.